# How to set the font size for cell.textLabel globally ( for all the tableView cells )

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is there a way to set the font size of cell's textLabel globally for all the TableView instead of setting it for every cell in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a `cell.textLabel.font` to a specific font, set it to a `UIFont` variable. You can then change the value of the variable (use the same font family but vary the size) and call `-reloadData` on the table view to force an update. I just tried this with a simple app to select the font size by selecting a row in a UI table view and it works a treat.

Comment: But that doesn't prevent what I want: avoid setting the cell size every time a cell is created. I want something I can call when I create the table view and remove the `cell.texlabel.font` code. Maybe just a dumb question.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought you were wanting for a way to change the font size as opposed to permanently setting it. In that case, I would definitely go with @jrturton's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could override UITableViewCell and set the font size in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier, after calling the super version.